# Datatables Columna control cambio resolucion

Tags: datatables

Tengo una datable dónde muestro los datos de una tabla, tengo configurada la primera columna como control para que en móviles o resoluciones pequeñas muestre el control '+' y se puedan ver todos los datos de la tabla que no se ven en la vista. Lo hace correctamente, pero el caso es que en la última columna tengo los botones de editar y borrar y cuando está en una resolución que se ven todas las columnas funciona correctamente, pero cuando está en una resolución que aparece en la primera columna el control se visualizan los botones de editar y borrar pero no se ejecuta el evento del botón.

Este es el código que tengo en el columndefs de la datatable para mostrar los botones de la última columna

```
{
            targets: 12,
                render: function(data, type, full, meta){
                            return "<center>"+
                                        "<span class='btnEditarEmpleado text-primary px-1'style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                                            "<i class='fas fa-pencil-alt fs-5'></i>"+
                                        "</span>"+
                                        "<span class='btnEliminarEmpleado text-danger px-1' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                                            "<i class='fas fa-trash fs-5'></i>"+
                                        "</span>"
                                    "</center>"
                    }
                
        }
```

y este es el código de la columna del control

```
{
                targets: 0,
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false
        },
```

El código del botón para la edición:

```
  // BOTON MODIFICAR EMPLEADO    
        $('#tbl_empleados tbody').on('click','.btnEditarEmpleado',function(){
            var data= table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var id= data["CodigoPropuesta"];
           
            
           CargarContenido('vistas/propuestas_edit.php?id='+id,'content-wrapper');
            
            
                    
        });
```

Comment: Falta información en la pregunta: ¿Cómo añades los *event listeners*?

Comment: añadida información @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0):

Ya he solucionado el problema, os cuento, en el render he pasado el parámetro row y al span le pongo los id-xxx que necesito para pasar las variables y en el evento ya recibo los datos.

el código correcto:

```
targets: 12,
                render: function(datqa, type, row, meta){
                    if (row.Estado=='Terminado')
                            {
                                return "<center>"+
                                        "<span id='btnmodpro' data-id='"+ datqa + " 'class='btnmodpro  text-success px-1'style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                                            "<i class='fas fa-arrow-right fs-5'></i>"+
                                        "</span>"+
                                    "</center>"
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return "<center>"+
                                        "<span id='btnmodpro' data-id='"+ datqa + " 'class='btnmodpro  text-primary px-1'style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                                            "<i class='fas fa-pencil-alt fs-5'></i>"+
                                        "</span>"+
                                        "<span id='btnelipro' data-estado='"+ row.Estado + "' data-cod='" + row.CodigoProyecto + "' data-tit='" + row.NombreProyecto + "'class='btnelipro text-danger px-1' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                                            "<i class='fas fa-trash fs-5'></i>"+
                                        "</span>"
                                    "</center>"

                            }
                           
                    }
```